# How can I return the inner value of a `MutexGuard` type?

Tags: multithreading, locking, rust

This is my example code:

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", test());
}

fn test() -> Vec<(u32, u32)> {
    let lock = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Vec::new()));
    let threads = Vec::new();

    for _ in 0..8 {
        let l = lock.clone();
        threads.push(thread::spawn(move || {
           let mut _lock = l.lock().unwrap();
           _lock.push((12, 28));
        }));
    }

    for t in threads { t.join(); }

    return lock.lock().unwrap();
}
```

The error is mismatched types: expected 'Vec' found 'MutextGuard', I've tested without 'lock()' also.

Is there a solution or a better approach to this kind of problem?